# How to use a HMODULE as a DWORD / Hex value? (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dword, readprocessmemory, base-address

I have a HMODULE value that equals: 00007FF695820000 and I need it to be 
0x7FF695820000 but because the value is the correct hex value converting it to hex just makes it an even bigger hex value.

Does anyone know a way I can simply add 0x to the start or make my ReadProcessMemory think this is a hex value not a decimal value.

The reason it's a HMODULE variable is because I'm using it to get the base address for Solitare.exe but currently can't read addresses from it because my ReadProcessMemory just converts it to hex first so reads the wrong address.

Comment: how does "converting it to hex just makes it an even bigger hex value"?

Comment: Those are 64 bit numbers, leave them be. Treat them as `void*` and `HANDLE`. Show the rest of your code.

Comment: "Does anyone know a way I can simply add 0x to the start" - are you sure you understand the difference between representation and actual value. You treat the number as if it's stored as a string inside memory. Hex and decimal are just string REPRESENTATIONS of numbers. The number is the same otherwise.

Comment: @ Lưu Vĩnh Phúc  It makes it a bigger hex value because Visual Studio thinks it's a decimal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioned address `00007FF695820000` is an `uint64_t` integer number. To call the function you should care about variable type, but not it's visual representation.

You can read the process memory in the following way:

```
UINT_PTR addr = (UINT_PTR)GetModuleHandle("Solitare.exe");
ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (void*)addr, pBuffer, nSize, &BytesRead);
```

To use `ReadProcessMemory` your `hProc` handle should have `PROCESS_VM_READ` access permission.

Comment: @Tom Nice to hear. If my answer is helpful to you, accept it please by ticking it on left side